# Struggling with pynput.keyboard import Listener and return values

Tags: python, pynput

I am trying to make a stopwatch in python. The problem I'm having is that my while loop does not stop when listener becomes false.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import time

def pressOn(key):
    x = 'Press: {}'.format(key)
    #this print function is for debugging
    print(x)
def pressOff(key):
    y = 'Release: {}'.format(key)
    #this print function is for debugging
    print(y)
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False
#t = time
t = 0
stop = True
with Listener(on_press = pressOn, on_release = pressOff) as listener:
    while True:
        print(f'it has been {t} seconds')
        t += 1
        time.sleep(1)
        if listener == False:
            break
    listener.join()

print(f'Final time {t} second(s)')
```

this is my output with no key presses

```
>>> it has been 0 seconds
>>> it has been 1 seconds
>>> it has been 2 seconds
```

and if I were to press then release the keys a, !, and esc between the 1 second message and the two second message I get this as my output

```
>>> it has been 0 seconds
>>> it has been 1 seconds
>>> Press: 'a'
>>> Release: 'a'
>>> Press: '!'
>>> Release: '!'
>>> Press: Key.esc
>>> Release: Key.esc
>>> it has been 2 seconds
```

The problem I am having is that when I press esc (the key that SHOULD end the program) it continues to count but won't register anymore inputs

ex: I press then release the 1 and esc key between the 0 and 1 second messages and then press any other key between 1 and 5 second messages

```
>>> it has been 0 seconds
>>> Press: '1'
>>> Release: '1'
>>> Press: Key.esc
>>> Release: Key.esc
>>> it has been 1 seconds
>>> it has been 2 seconds
>>> it has been 3 seconds
>>> it has been 4 seconds
>>> it has been 5 seconds
```

What I want to do instead is:

```
>>> it has been 0 seconds
>>> Press: '1'
>>> Release: '1'
>>> Press: Key.esc
>>> Release: Key.esc
>>> Final time 1 second(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

To stop the loop when the 'esc' key is pressed, you should set the stop variable to False inside the pressOff function. Then, you can check the value of stop in the while loop condition.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import time

def pressOn(key):
    x = 'Press: {}'.format(key)
    print(x)

def pressOff(key):
    y = 'Release: {}'.format(key)
    print(y)
    if key == Key.esc:
        global stop
        stop = False
        return False

t = 0
stop = True

with Listener(on_press=pressOn, on_release=pressOff) as listener:
    while stop:
        print(f'it has been {t} seconds')
        t += 1
        time.sleep(1)

    listener.join()

print(f'Final time {t} second(s)')
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't even think about that, thanks. :)